# to design three vertical Axes in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, graphs

Would you mind helping me in drawing three vertical axes to explain that for each time `t_{1}, t_{2}, ..., t_{i}` there is a corresponding price `p_{1}, p_{2}, ..., p_{i}` and a corresponding volume `v_{1}, v_{2}, ..., v_{i}`.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SE! Can you provide at least simple sketch how your drawing should be?

Answer (score 1):

A quick suggestion:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,2,4}
  {
  \draw (\x cm,0) -- (\x cm,4);
  \node [right] at (\x cm + 2pt,2.5) {$\vdots$};
  }

\foreach \x/\p in {0/t,2/p,4/v}
   \foreach  \y/\t in {0.5/1,1.5/2,3.5/i}
       \draw (\x cm-2pt,\y) -- (\x cm+2pt,\y) node [right] {$\p_{\t}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]